# Java- Setting a image as a background through ImageIO gives an error upon compilation

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to set a background image for this window and I have tried multiple ways but I am compiling/saving it, it's giving an error as shown below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class Admin_hs extends JFrame {

JButton bking_btn= new JButton("Bookings");
JButton fd_btn= new JButton("Financial Data");
JButton ctm_btn= new JButton("Customers");
JButton room_btn= new JButton("Rooms");
JButton adc_btn= new JButton("Additional Costs");
JButton endb_btn= new JButton("Ending Bookings");

//Images
JLabel bking_img= new JLabel();
JLabel fd_img= new JLabel();
JLabel ctm_img= new JLabel();
JLabel room_img= new JLabel();
JLabel adc_img= new JLabel();
JLabel endb_img= new JLabel();
JLabel logout= new JLabel(); 
JLabel copyrightL = new JLabel("Hotel Management System \u00a9 2016");
private BufferedImage image;
///Panels

JPanel pnl1= new JPanel();//panel for buttons and images
JPanel pnl2= new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());//panel for copyright label
JPanel pnl3= new JPanel(); //panel for logout button


///Constructors

public Admin_hs(){

    this.setTitle("Welcome Admin!");
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    ///Setting a layout
    pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    logout.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/logout.jpg"));

     pnl3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //logout = new JLabel( "Logout" );
        pnl3.add(logout, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.EAST,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6), 0, 0));

    //background image
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("‪C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/simple-blue.jpg"));

            this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    ///First Column of Grid
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth= GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.fill= gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    bking_btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    bking_btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    pnl1.add(bking_btn, gc);


    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    fd_btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    fd_btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    pnl1.add(fd_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    ctm_btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    ctm_btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    pnl1.add(ctm_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    room_btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    room_btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    pnl1.add(room_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    adc_btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    adc_btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    pnl1.add(adc_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 5;
    endb_btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    endb_btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130,30));
    pnl1.add(endb_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    pnl1.add(copyrightL, gc);


    /////second column of grid



    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    bking_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/ReserveNowIcon.png"));
    pnl1.add(bking_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    fd_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/booking.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(fd_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    ctm_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/guest.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(ctm_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    room_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/room.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(room_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    adc_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/fd.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(adc_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 5;
    endb_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/endb.png"));
    pnl1.add(endb_img, gc);


    pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        pnl2.add(copyrightL, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(pnl3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(pnl1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(pnl2, gbc);

        this.setSize(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

}
```

**Main**

```
 public class Admin_main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Admin_hs adm= new Admin_hs();

    adm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    adm.pack();
    adm.setVisible(true);
    adm.setSize(800,701);

     }
```

}

I have added images on the window using `setIcon` but I didn't get this problem upon compilation. Even when I am commenting out all the lines added for the background image, I am getting the same error. Only when I remove it that I am able run it.

Here is a pic to get an idea of how it looks:
[image]

**EDIT**
When I clicked on "Save as UTF", it's throwing an exception:

[image]

I would like to know any alternative ways of how I can set a background image as I have tried overriding the paint method also but it didn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: And when you did as directed, when you clicked on "Save as UTF-8", what happened?

Comment: If that doesn't work, give the image a simpler name, one without unusual characters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited my post and added an image of what happened when I saved as UTF.. I then gave the image a simple name and the same exception was thrown upon compilation

Comment: I would like to know any reasons for the downvote :/

Comment: The main reason you can't read the image is because it doesn't exist at the specified location or it's not a format that ImageIO can read

Comment: You're still using unusual chars in your code -- `\u00a9`. And is your code file name/path the correct one now?

Comment: Also, JPanel is opaque by default, so it's likely to cover the image

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, the file name/path is correct.. the `\u00a9` is for the copyright symbol `@ ` used in the label at the bottom..

Comment: @MadProgrammer The image's location is correct.. I have changed its location also but getting the same error

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you give me alternative ways of how to set a background image?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Any alternative ways of how to set a background image?

Comment: @MadProgrammer "Also, JPanel is opaque by default, so it's likely to cover the image" What do you mean by that?

Comment: And JPanel is not transparent, so when you add it the label, it will cover part of the image...what else does plaque mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I took your code, replaced the background image with one of my own and ran it...

[image: Background]

So, either `C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/simple-blue.jpg` doesn't exist or isn't an image format that `ImageIO` can read.

Also, as you can see, the `JPanel` is opaque, so it doesn't show the background beneath it. You will need to change the `opaque` property to `false`

The encoding problem is associated with the inclusion of unicode characters (`\u00a9`) and if you save the file as UTF-8 it should solve the problem.

The layout issue is because you've used a `FlowLayout` (`this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`) for the `contentPane`

Now, before you tell me the image is fine, I have a running example which says otherwise

Comment: is it the '-' (dash or minus) in the file name simple-blue.jpg ? if i.e. gimp can open it JVM should also...

Comment: I don't know, I don't have access to your computer

Comment: @MadProgrammer I really don't know what's wrong because the image path is correct as it is with other images which I have used which are showing up.. I changed the image, path, format(used .png) but getting the same error.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I removed the encoding but it threw the same exception

Comment: *"same exception"* isn't very informative. Here's a problem, all I did with your code was change the image of the background and removed all the other `ImageIcon` references and it worked just fine - maybe you should start by commenting out all the images and see if that works, re-introducing one at a time to see which one doesn't work.

Comment: Anime. Does it always have to be anime? ;) 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You honestly have to ask the question ... sometimes it ponies!

Comment: @MadProgrammer By same exception, I meant this `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)` and it points to the line where the image is being read `ImageIO.read`

Comment: @Diksha Okay, it's time to find and use a different file. You need to verify that the exists, which you can use `File#exists` for. You should also test to see that the image can be loaded by another program as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot! I loaded the image(simple-blue.jpg) I used in another new program and it didn't work at first, then added a new image in the same program and it worked. Then I added the first image to the same new  program and somehow it worked. I added the image path simple-blue.jpg in the program which I posted here again and I don't know how but it worked!

Comment: I have set the panel's opacity to false..I am having some problem with the layout though.. When I am calling `this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`, the labels and images are getting distorted like in the screenshot you posted and  when I am not calling it, the background image is covering everything so that only the background image is appearing. How can I fix that?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any suggestions? I am new to Java (and Layouts) so would appreciate your help

Comment: `BorderLayout`, `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Thanks. BorderLayout covered the all the components but GridBagLayout worked partly

Comment: I fixed it by setting the GridBagLayout before adding the panels to JFrame as I guess the constraints are not saved by the layout manager, since by default a JLabel (which is now the content pane) uses a null layout until specifically the layout is set.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` needs to be setup with the conrrect constraints